# Upgrading material-ui v3 to v4 causes redux form Field component error 'invalid prop component'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, redux-form

After upgrading from *material-ui v3 to v4* I get the following error for all my `<Field>` components containing the prop `component`.

**Error:**

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to
> `Field`.

The Field component comes from `import { Field } from 'redux-form';`

The component looks like this:

```
        <Field
            id="some-id"
            name="some-name"
            component={renderSelectField}
        />
```

The code compiles and runs fine.

the renderSelectField component:

```
 <TextField
            select
            id={label}
            label={label}
            type={label}
            value={value}
            SelectProps={{
                MenuProps: {
                    PaperProps: {
                        style: {
                            maxHeight: 500,
                            paddingLeft: 12,
                            paddingRight: 12,
                        },
                    },
                },
            }}
            onChange={onChange}
        >
```

Comment: What is `renderSelectField`?

Comment: Show code for the `renderSelectField` component please.

Comment: Updated the code and added the needed component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the following React dependencies (react redux v7, redux form v8):

```
"react-redux": "^7.2.1",
"redux-form": "^8.3.6",
```

Explanation:

After material-ui upgrade you most probably will see the forwardRef error in the console. React.forwardRef is used in the new version of MUI and react hooks.

Previously react, redux versions only allowed specific data types to be assigned to the component prop, however the new versions allow many more.